# Resize the UITabBar (image)

Tags: swift, resize, uitabbar

I recently changed my TabBar image to my own made bar(See photos for reference). When I run it in the Iphone 5s simulator, it's the perfect size. But when I run it on the Iphone 6, it's doesn't automatically resize, so it stops where the Iphone 5s would have stopped(Picture 2). How do I get the TabBar image to resize?

**Update**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


     UITabBar.appearance().translucent = true
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()




    UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().makeImageWithColorAndSize(UIColor(red: 127.0 / 255.0, green: 217.0 / 255.0, blue: 255.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0), size: CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.width/5, tabBar.frame.height))


    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(named:"officialbar")



}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with auto layout and constraints? You do not have to open every simulator to see how does it look on different devices.

You can open `Storyboard` -> click on the assistant editor[image] -> Now where it says "Manual"[image] on the upper thing click on "Preview"[image]

And now you can mess around more easily with constraints and see right after change how it looks like on different screen sizes.

Comment: Didn't know you could use auto layout on the Tab Bar

Comment: But it's also a custom image as a tab bar, so It doesn't show up in the main.storyboard preview

Comment: You see it there if you drop image into your project folder not into xcassets.

Comment: It still does not work. The autoresizing options are locked and can't be changed

Comment: Upload your project to github or somewhere and I will take a look.